# Is it possible to send data via postMessage then let the target iframe store the data to react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, iframe, postmessage

I have two React Apps with redux.
**example1** has an iframe **example2**.

I want to pass data from example1 to example2 via `postMessage`, and let the example2 save the data to state once it received the post message.

Is it possible to achieve the goal? I have tried to do it like the below code, but nothing happened.

Thanks.

// example1.com

```
function App() {

  const sendPostMessage = () => {
    window.postMessage('hello there!', '*')
  }

  return (
    <div>
     <button onClick={sendPostMessage}>Click Me</button>
     <iframe
       title="iframe example"
       src="http://example2.com"
       width="600"
       height="400"
     />
    </div>
  )
}
```

// exmaple2.com

```
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("No data");
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  
      setMessage(event.data);  // want to save data to redux or state
      
    });
  }, []);

  return (
   <div>
    <p>{message}</p>
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Who do you think `window` is in the main page? That's the one you've been posting a message to. You'll need to wait the iframe document has loaded so that you can talk to its window (accessible though `iframe.contentWindow`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As you mentioned, I have to select the iframe from my main page, so after I update my code to 
 `iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage()` , my iframe can receive the data from parent.